# TableView stop reuse

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display users for a messaging app in a TableView however when I scroll it updates the cells and therefore pulls the data again thus lagging. I am using a prototype cell in a storyboard.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var profilePicture: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    override func prepareForReuse() -> Void {
        profilePicture.image = nil
        statusImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
        nameLabel.text = nil
    }
}

class MainController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViews: UITableView!

    var users = [String]()
    var decryptedUsers = [String]()

    @IBAction func signOut(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
                let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                let dbReference = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userid!).child("status")
            dbReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, andPreviousSiblingKeyWith: { snapshot,error in
                if (snapshot.value as? String == "online") {
                    dbReference.setValue("offline")
                }
            })
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToSignIn", sender: nil)
        } catch {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "There was an error signing out. Please ensure that you are connected to the internet.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(okButton)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setOnline()
        fetchUsers()
    }

    static var userslist = [String]()

    func fetchUsers() {
        let userid = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
        let dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("Chatlist").child(userid)
        dbRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot, error) in
            self.users.removeAll()
            for yeet in snapshot.children {
                let yeetsnap = yeet as! DataSnapshot
                self.users.append(yeetsnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "id").value as! String)

                print(self.users)
                self.tableViews.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func setOnline() {
        let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let dbReference = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userid!).child("status")
        dbReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, andPreviousSiblingKeyWith: { snapshot,error in
            if (snapshot.value as? String == "offline") {
                dbReference.setValue("online")
            }
        })
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: TableViewCell?
        cell = nil
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellProto") as? TableViewCell)!
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell!.profilePicture.layer.masksToBounds = true
                cell!.profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = (cell!.profilePicture.bounds.width) / 2
                cell!.statusImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
                cell!.statusImage.layer.cornerRadius = (cell!.statusImage.bounds.width) / 2
                let dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(self.users[indexPath.row])
                dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                    cell!.nameLabel?.text = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as? String
                    let urlstring = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "imageURL").value as? String
                    if (urlstring != "default") {
                        let url = URL(string: urlstring!)
                        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                        cell!.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data:  data!)
                    }
                    let statusstring = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "status").value as? String
                    if (statusstring == "online") {
                        cell!.statusImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
                    } else if (statusstring == "offline") {
                        cell!.statusImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray
                    } else if (statusstring == "appearoffline") {
                        cell!.statusImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray
                    } else if (statusstring == "dnd") {
                        cell!.statusImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRed
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        print("test")
        return cell!
    }
}
```

Comment: When you first download the data, store it. If you’ve already got stored data for a row, don’t download it again.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this. And I would rather just stop the reuse.

Comment: Don't stop the reuse. Do it properly.

Comment: You cannot and should not stop reuse. How to populate a table view with downloaded data is a well solved problem. You’re not the first and you’re not special in this regard. Try searching. This has been thoroughly explained many times here already.

Comment: I have solved the issue by storing the data. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do not load the data every time within the cellForRow. This reloads the data every time you scroll, causing the table to lag.

A better approach would be to load the data once by putting the database retrieving code in here:

```
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // retrieve the data here by calling a separate function
}
```

Whatever you do, it is not a good coding approach to load data within the cellForRow method.

You can also retrieve the data by calling the function whenever the user swipes down from the top of the table to reload the table.

One more option would be to only load a number of rows at once (10 max for example), then when the user scroll to the bottom of the 10 rows and keeps scrolling it will then retrieve the next 10 datapoints for the next 10 rows in the table.